# How to enable linum-mode only during I-search?

Tags: isearch, linum-mode

- `linum-line` it not enabled when emacs is started.

I just want to enable linum-mode (see the line numbers) during `I-search` and disable it when `I-search:` is ended. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the built-in line-numbering feature that comes with Emacs 26?  The reason I ask is because the answer will be different if you have specifically chosen to use a deprecated Lisp method to generate line numbers; e.g., `linum-mode` or `nlinum`.

Comment: Oh there is no reason at all. I was just using `goto-line-with-feedback` if I want to see line-numbers but I don't know on the background which line-feature it is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, one would not have to worry about line numbers at all: the various tools would cooperate to put you in the right place. However, there are holes in the coverage, so you occasionally need to know on what line you are and  how to get to a given line.

As @lawlist points out, it would be preferable to use `display-line-number-mode` - see the [EmacsWiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers) for details. That takes care of knowing where you are and, in my case, binding `goto-line` to a key takes cares of the second. AFAIK, this is *much* more efficient than `linum-mode` (which I am not using, but which, when I tried it out many years ago, was very unresponsive, although undoubtedly it is much better than it was).

If you still want to turn it on and off in `isearch`, you can try using `isearch-mode-hook` and `isearch-mode-end-hook`. Something like this (minimally tested):

```el
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 0)))
```

This is bog-standard emacs [customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html#Hooks): the only thing that you have to research is whether the appropriate hooks are available, which is generally easy to do by using `C-h v isearch--hook TAB` in this case, taking advantage on one hand of the universal convention of hook naming (`<prefix>-<type>-hook`) and on the other hand the standard completion mechanism (which will expand the `--` in the middle, giving you all the variables that start with `isearch-` and end with `-hook`). IMO, this is a very useful trick and is worth remembering.

Comment: I tired the code related ot `add-hook`  but it did not show the line numbers :-(

Comment: Try it starting with `emacs -q` - you apparently have a lot of stuff in your init file which causes problems. In any case, I "minimally tested" to make sure that the numbers show up when you start an isearch and go away when you exit.

Comment: You are right my init file is little bit mess :-) It works with `emacs -q`. I will try to figure out what is prevents it by removing some lines. And thanks for the trick advice