# How to discard line-number highlight during i-search?

Tags: themes, isearch, linum-mode

During the `i-search` if I use [`dracula` theme](https://github.com/dracula/emacs) it highlights the line-number if the searched word is the first in the line.

Example view:

[image]

---

If I uncomment `(load-theme 'dracula t)` the example view would be where line number is not highlighted:

[image]

---

==> I just want to disable the highlight option for line numbers for a specific theme, is it possible? How to discard line-number highlight during i-search?

---

my setup:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'dracula t)

(setq linum-format "%d ")
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 0)))
(delete-selection-mode 1) ;; Overwrite selected text

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-w") 'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)

(defadvice isearch-repeat (after isearch-no-fail activate)
  (unless isearch-success
    (ad-disable-advice 'isearch-repeat 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-repeat)
    (isearch-repeat (if isearch-forward 'forward))
    (ad-enable-advice 'isearch-repeat 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-repeat)))

(define-advice isearch-repeat (:before (direction) goto-other-end)
  "If reversing, start the search from the other end of the current match."
  (unless (eq isearch-forward (eq direction 'forward))
    (when isearch-other-end
      (goto-char isearch-other-end))))
```

Comment: Why are you using `linum-mode`, instead of the built-in line numbers that Eli Z. implemented starting from Emacs 26 and forwards?  `linum-mode` is officially deprecated.  The replacement is `display-line-numbers-mode` / `global-display-line-numbers-mode`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Display-Custom.html

Comment: I was using `linum-mode` due to this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59844/18414 , should I change `linum-mode` with `display-line-numbers-mode` ?

Comment: For buffers with not too many lines, the performance will not make a difference.  For buffers with many lines and/or folded (invisible) lines, the performance hit will be noticeable.  Some forum participants may hesitate to write-up an answer that relies upon a feature that has been deprecated.  The slow-down in performance is that `linum-mode` relies upon `count-lines`, which is slow in longer buffers.  The built-in line number written by Eli Z. does not rely upon `count-lines` and lines numbers are drawn during redisplay and prepended to the display line.  `linum-mode` uses overlays / margin

Comment: @lawlist Thanks changing `linum-mode` into `display-line-numbers-mode` fixed the issue